# Measure difference of two images using emgucv

Tags: c#, image-processing, compare, emgucv

i need to compare two images and identify differences on them as percentage. "Absdiff" function on emgucv doesn't help with that. i already done that compare example on emgucv wiki.  what i exactly want is how to get two image difference in numerical format?

```
//emgucv wiki compare example

//acquire the frame
Frame = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame(); //aquire a frame
 Difference = Previous_Frame.AbsDiff(Frame);
//what i want is
double differenceValue=Previous_Frame."SOMETHING";
```

if you need more detail plz ask.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using the MatchTemplate function? Use one image as the template and the other as the image to be matched.  This results in a single numerical value (float) that corresponds to how well the two images correlate.  Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

**EmguCV MatchTemplate based comparison**

```
Bitmap inputMap = //bitmap  source image
Image<Gray, Byte> sourceImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(inputMap);

Bitmap tempBitmap = //Bitmap template image
Image<Gray, Byte> templateImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(tempBitmap);

Image<Gray, float> resultImage = sourceImage.MatchTemplate(templateImage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed);

double[] minValues, maxValues;
Point[] minLocations, maxLocations;
resultImage.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLocations, out maxLocations);

double percentage = maxValues[0] * 100; //this will be percentage of difference of two images
```

The two images need to have the same width and height or MatchTemplate will throw an exception. In case if we want to have an exact match.
Or
The template image should be smaller than the source image to get a number of occurrence of the template image on the source image

Comment: Just a note that the two images need to have the same width and height or `MatchTemplate` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

**EmguCV AbsDiff based comparison**

```
Bitmap inputMap = //bitmap  source image
Image<Gray, Byte> sourceImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(inputMap);

Bitmap tempBitmap = //Bitmap template image
Image<Gray, Byte> templateImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(tempBitmap);

Image<Gray, byte> resultImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(templateImage.Width, 
templateImage.Height);

CvInvoke.AbsDiff(sourceImage, templateImage, resultImage);

double diff = CvInvoke.CountNonZero(resultImage);

diff = (diff / (templateImage.Width * templateImage.Height)) * 100; // this will give you the difference in percentage
```

As per my experience, this is the best method compared to MatchTemplate based comparison. Match template failed to capture very minimal changes in two images.
But AbsDiff will be able to capture very small difference as well